# My wireless is connected but no internet access using Windows 7 laptop

Tags: wireless-router

I've tried many things to get my wireless connected reading other people's posts,but it still wont work.Please help... this is what my computer is showing...

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Amandeep>ipconfig/all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Amandeep-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Mobile Broadband adapter Mobile Broadband Connection 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Vodafone Mobile Broadband Network Adapter
 (Huawei) #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 58-2C-80-13-92-63
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 120.22.130.13(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 120.22.130.14
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 120.22.130.14
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.143.147.147
                                       10.143.147.148
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : F4-6D-04-2D-4B-2D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E0-B9-A5-1D-15-4E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:7816:820d::7816:820d(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 2002:c058:6301::c058:6301
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.143.147.147
                                       10.143.147.148
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:4137:9e76:3c:3f48:87e9:7df2(Prefer
red)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3c:3f48:87e9:7df2%13(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{1A946F8C-A99B-4AB6-9440-FD47EB94303D}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{D0957907-4A25-4246-9A84-59F058BA3295}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C97A756B-DDE1-4514-A421-AED82CFE8E45}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\Users\Amandeep>
```

Comment: Looks like your wireless adaptor isn't connected. Does it detect any APs at all?

Comment: Why is this tagged `wireless-router`? What is the actual problem? Why do you think your wireless isn't connected?